# Equivalent of index - match in Excel to return greater than the lookup value

Tags: r, excel, indexing, match, lookup

In R I need to perform a similar function to index-match in Excel which returns the value just greater than the look up value.

Data Set A

```
Country     GNI2009           
Ukraine     6604
Egypt       5937
Morocco     5307
Philippines 4707
Indonesia   4148
India       3677
Viet Nam    3180
Pakistan    2760
Nigeria     2699
```

Data Set B

```
GNI2004 s1  s2  s3  s4
6649    295 33  59  3
6021    260 30  50  3
5418    226 27  42  2
4846    193 23  35  2
4311    162 20  29  2
3813    134 16  23  1
3356    109 13  19  1
2976    89  10  15  1
2578    68  7   11  0
2248    51  5   8   0
2199    48  5   8   0
```

At the 2009 level GNI for each country (data set A) I would like to find out which GNI2004 is just greater than or equal to  GNI2009 and then return the corresponding sales values (s1,s2...) at that row (data set B). I would like to repeat this for each and every Country-gni row for 2009 in table A.

For example: `Nigeria` with a `GNI2009 of 2698` in data set A would return:

```
GNI2004 s1  s2  s3  s4
2976    89  10  15  1
```

In Excel I guess this would be something like Index and Match where the match condition would be `match(look up value, look uparray,-1)`

Comment: Please see [ask] questions.

Comment: Hi, How do I put in numbers in a table as others do while citing an example? thanks

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Im guessing its fine now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `data.table`s rolling join which designed to achieve just that

```
library(data.table) # V1.9.6+
indx <- setDT(DataB)[setDT(DataA), roll = -Inf, on = c(GNI2004 = "GNI2009"), which = TRUE]
DataA[, names(DataB) := DataB[indx]]
DataA  
#        Country GNI2009 GNI2004  s1 s2 s3 s4
# 1:     Ukraine    6604    6649 295 33 59  3
# 2:       Egypt    5937    6021 260 30 50  3
# 3:     Morocco    5307    5418 226 27 42  2
# 4: Philippines    4707    4846 193 23 35  2
# 5:   Indonesia    4148    4311 162 20 29  2
# 6:       India    3677    3813 134 16 23  1
# 7:    Viet Nam    3180    3356 109 13 19  1
# 8:    Pakistan    2760    2976  89 10 15  1
# 9:     Nigeria    2699    2976  89 10 15  1
```

The idea here is per each row in `GNI2009` find the closest equal/bigger value in `GNI2004`, get the row index and subset. Then we update `DataA` with the result.

---

See [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for more information.

Comment: thanks. but befor i get to that,  the moment i try to run library(data.table) it says there is no such package even though i have installed it using install.packages.

Comment: Says some dependencies are unavailable , initially it tried a number of mirrors though

Comment: Try `install.packages("data.table", dependencies = TRUE)` or `install.packages("data.table", dependencies = "Depends")`. See `?install.packages` for more details.

Comment: Works! THanks :) I had tried install.packages("data.table", dep= T, "install path") wonder what was wrong

Comment: Hey thanks for the help works like a charm :) just to understand if I were to pick up the value lesser than the look up value instead of the value greater how wud the code change ?

Comment: Use `Inf` instead of `-Inf`